# Inserting from one table or view into another but avoid combination duplicates- Can this be done in SQL? If so how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, duplicates

I have a table that has a primary key WORKITEMID, and the following 3 foreign keys PRODSERVID,PROCESSID,and TASKKNOWID.

I have a view that I can create that also has PRODSERVID,PROCESSID, AND TASKKNOWID. This view will usually have ALL the records in above table plus some new ones - not in the table. The 'table' by definition is meant to hold the unique combinations of PRODSERVID, PROCESSID, and TASKKNOWID.

I would like to insert from the view into the table any new combinations in the view not present in the table. And I don't want to overwrite the existing WORKITEMIDs in the INSERT- because those WORKITEMIDs are used elsewhere.

Can this be done in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, the simplest form of criteria for this is to use the negation of [EXISTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15%5D)

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] (PRODSERVID,PROCESSID,TASKKNOWID,... )
SELECT PRODSERVID,PROCESSID,TASKKNOWID,...
FROM [ViewName] v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM [TableName] t
    WHERE t.PRODSERVID = v.PRODSERVID AND t.PROCESSID = v.PROCESSID AND t.TASKKNOWID = v.TASKKNOWID
)
```

*replace the `...` with your other fields*

You could also use a non-corellating outer join but I find not exists makes the intent much clearer.

> There is a good comparison of the different approaches to this issue in this article: [T-SQL commands performance comparison – NOT IN vs SQL NOT EXISTS vs SQL LEFT JOIN vs SQL EXCEPT](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-commands-performance-comparison-not-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-vs-except/)